# Disable OnClickListener while scaling or dragging a View

Tags: android, scale, onclicklistener, drag, mpandroidchart

Hi I'm using MPAndroidChart and my added OnClickListener is triggered right after i zoomed into or dragged a chart. How can i disable this behavior?

This are my chart properties:

```
chart.setTouchEnabled(true);        
chart.setScaleEnabled(true);
chart.setDragEnabled(true);        
chart.setPinchZoom(true);
chart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //this only should run if i really click on the chart, not if i zoom or drag it.
        ...     
    });
```

Is there an easy way to do it? This ClickListener, ScaleListener and ScaleGestureDetector gang bang ist kinda complicated :/

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `ScaleGestureDetector` in http://android-developers.blogspot.com.tr/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html .
At onScale Event, remove the `OnClickListener` with `chart.setOnClickListener(null)`. Then Implement an `OnTouchListener` and add `onClickListener` at `ACTION_UP`.

This should allow you to avoid triggering onClick events at pinch to zoom.

Comment: Ive written my own myBarChart class  and extended it by the BarChart. In my class i wrote a methode setScaleGestureDetector(). I used it to set the Detector. So now when i scale myBarChart the codes doesnt go into onScale() in debug mode... Isnt it the right way to implement them? how do i go into onScale()? :/