# Disable click on chart

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I am using multiple mpandroidchart in a scrollview with a linearlayout.

The thing is is i want to disable any kind of horizontal/verical scrolling in the charts because that causes problem when i'm scrolling down to next chart. I've tried setting the clickable attribute to false but that doesn't help. **Is there any method in the library to disable any kind of touch event on chart?** I would like  it to be fully static.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the `OnChartGestureListener` from library : [OnChartGestureListener](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart).

**Enabling / disabling interaction**

- `setTouchEnabled(boolean enabled)`: Allows to enable/disable all
  possible touch-interactions with the chart.
- `setDragEnabled(boolean enabled)`: Enables/disables dragging (panning)
  for the chart.
- `setScaleEnabled(boolean enabled)`: Enables/disables scaling for the
  chart on both axes.
- `setScaleXEnabled(boolean enabled)`: Enables/disables scaling on the
  x-axis.
- `setScaleYEnabled(boolean enabled)`: Enables/disables scaling on the
  y-axis.
- `setPinchZoom(boolean enabled)`: If set to true, pinch-zooming is
  enabled. If disabled, x- and y-axis can be zoomed separately.

and many more...

Please check this answer [Disable OnClickListener while scaling or dragging a View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257322/disable-onclicklistener-while-scaling-or-dragging-a-view).

Comment: i just needed this part : barchart.setTouchEnabled(false). Thanks.